# Uncaught ReferenceError: Crime is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a onclick="genreInput(Crime)">Crime</a>
                    <a onclick="genreInput(Thriller)">Thriller</a>
                    <a onclick="genreInput(Drama)">Drama</a>
                    <a onclick="genreInput(Mystery)">Mystery</a>
                    <a onclick="genreInput(War)">War</a>
                    <a onclick="genreInput(Comedy)">Comedy</a>
function genreInput(Input){return Input};
```

```
   function genre(){
  let newArray = movies.map((input)=>{
    return{
      title : input.title,
      genre : input.genre
    }
    });
    let filter = newArray.filter((input)=>{
      let x = genreInput();
      if(input.genre.includes(x)){
        return input.title
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('mainDiv').innerHTML = filer;
}
```

I'm getting undefined when I click the button that function is supposed to be used for the other function. What should I do.

Comment: Pass the argument as string, wrap the crime in quotes like 'Crime'.

Comment: How you are calling `genre()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a onclick="genreInput('Crime')">Crime</a>
  <a onclick="genreInput('Thriller')">Thriller</a>
  <a onclick="genreInput('Drama')">Drama</a>
  <a onclick="genreInput('Mystery')">Mystery</a>
  <a onclick="genreInput('War')">War</a>
  <a onclick="genreInput('Comedy')">Comedy</a>
</div>
```

Wrap the word with `''`

Furthermore, I've found 1 typo

```
function genre() {
  let newArray = movies.map((input) => {
    return {
      title: input.title,
      genre: input.genre
    }
  });
  let filter = newArray.filter((input) => {
    let x = genreInput();
    if (input.genre.includes(x)) {
      return input.title
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('mainDiv').innerHTML = filter;
}
```

I fixed some mistakes in your code, but I don't know what are you doing, 
There're so many unproperly used things.